# PHP global variable doesn't work when using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [global variables in php not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107693/global-variables-in-php-not-working-as-expected)

I have a php function that runs on every page of a website, it use a global variable, for example:

```
$var = "test";
function test() {
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}
```

This works fine when accessing /anyFile.php directly, but the website uses an htaccess file to rewrite urls, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^action/(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

When an url is rewrited by the htaccess, the function doesn't work, the $var is not set.

**What could be this happening and how can I fix it?** (I NEED to use "global", otherwise I'd need to recode a lot of things.

Comment: Your `$var` wasn't defined in global context, as probably (that's the code you didn't show) index.php invokes the action script from a function (=local scope).

Comment: Post your actual code.  Apache cannot affect PHP variables unless passed in `$_GET`, except if register_globals is On, which it _shouldn't be!!!!_

Comment: Are these lines together? mod_rewrite does not influence php... There must be something else happenning or $var is being modified in other place.

Comment: The code I didn't show is irrelevant, and too long to post it here. I tested it with the exact function i posted in the question, it works when visiting /index.php?action=anything, but it doesn't work ($var is not set) when visiting /action/anything. I tried $GLOBAL['var'], and it's also not set on the second url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[QSA,L]` instead of `[L]`:

```
RewriteRule ^action/(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

QSA stands for [Query String Append](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString), and forwards the query string (the part after the `?` in the url) to the PHP script.

By the way, you should **not** use [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) (*deprecated* as of PHP 5.3 and **removed** as of PHP 5.4), but use the `$_GET` [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) instead.

--- edit ---

Following your comment below (*you can't modify the .htaccess*), you're out of luck. Your only solution is to parse the query string in the request URI, and use that as you would use the `$_GET` superglobal:

```php
$queryString = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($queryString, $query);
echo $query['action'];
```

I strongly advise you to get the `.htaccess` modified for you, though.

Comment: The htaccess is from a script not my code so I don't think i will be modifying that, i may break something. I also tried $GLOBAL['var'], but its not set on the rewrited urls.