# Session variables not accessible after a hyperlink is used within the same domain

Tags: php, href

I have a web page written in PHP7 that uses session variables to pass data between pages. So far this has worked when using a redirect Header: type command, but for the life of me I cannot get it to work when using an  link.

When my app goes to a page using this for example

```
<a class="" href="page2.php" accesskey="2" title="Page2"></a>
```

None of the session variables are accessible.

I ran tests on the page2.php to see what was happening and got these results:

```
The session status is: 2
Session id is 90dg0e5opfrj8ojqvcm11okif7
Cookie domain is
session file: /var/lib/php/sessions/sess_90dg0e5opfrj8ojqvcm11okif7 size: 174
Displaying GLOBALS:
```

I checked the sessions folder and the file is indeed in there and does have the session variables, and yes I do have a session_start at the top of the page. In fact I tried it with it not being there and it didn't make any difference.

I also check on the calling page that the session ID was the same and it is.

I am completely stumped and cannot figure out why, even though PHP clearly knows what the session is, can obviously write to it but does not want to play ball?

Any clues?

Comment: how to you set session please share your session set code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just realised that I am looking at the wrong thing.

When I checked $_SESSION array they are there.
What I am looking for is global variables which it's forgetting.

Even defining a global in the previous page doesn't seem to always work.

I have read that globals are a bad thing, so I'm going to check what alternatives I have to using globals.

I saw this in Stackoverflow which explained what was wrong

[global variables in php not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107693/global-variables-in-php-not-working-as-expected)

$var = "test"; // this is accessible in all the rest of the code, even an included one

```
function foo2()
{
    global $var;
    echo $var; // this print "test"
    $var = 'test2';
}

 global $var; // this is totally useless, unless this file is included inside a class or function
```

That last line explains to me why its not working.
Makes a lot of sense now.